# Selecting div by id and class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to select this, using both is and class:

```
<div class="phase" id="1">
```

and nothing works, I tried:

```
.phase#1
#1.phase
div#1.phase
```

could it be the `#1`? I never ran into problems with a numeric id

**Update:**
It seems I confused jQuery selectors and CSS selectors,
this would work fine with jQuery:

```
$(".phase#1")
```

but this:

```
.phase#1 {}
```

Will not work in CSS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).
So if you selected by id you shouldn't also selected by class.

Specifies a unique id for the element. Naming rules:

1. Must begin with a letter A-Z or a-z
2. Can be followed by: letters
   (A-Za-z), digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"), and underscores ("_")
3. In HTML, all values are case-insensitive

[HTML id Attribute specification](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp)

Comment: "So if you selected by id you shouldn't also selected by class." But what if I want to select an element with an ID, only if it has a certain class?

Comment: Do you want make it with css or jquery selectors?

Answer (score 11):

`id`'s cannot start with numeric values `1, 2, 3, etc`. They can contain numeric values, just not start with them.

spec - http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

Comment: Note that this is not the case in HTML5: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: @JamesAllardice noted, though i'd shy away from absurdity like this `id="i-just-♥-this-sub-navigation„ø¤º°¨¨°º¤ø ¸„ø¤º°¨¨°º¤ø"`